# Firebase functions crashes while accessing firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Could you please find an error in following code?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();



exports.GetShort = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    longURL = request.query.long
    functions.logger.info("url is - " ,longURL)
    SaveToDB(longURL)
})


function SaveToDB(link){
    functions.logger.info("here")
    admin.firestore().collection("url").where("urlNames","array_contains",link).get().then(
  
        function(querySnapshot){
            functions.logger.info("snap, " ,querySnapshot)
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            functions.logger.info("things :  " ,doc.id, " => ", doc.data())

                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            });
        }
    ) .catch(function(error) {
        functions.logger.info("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}
```

After hitting above function, firebase-functions logs displays logs till **"here"**. After that it crashes without any more logs/stacktrace.

below is the contents of packages.json from functions directory.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would kindly suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) to see how to manage the life cycle of a Cloud Function and the way to deal with calls to asynchronous methods.

In particular, for an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), you need to end it with  `send()`, `redirect()`, or `end()`.

So your code could be adapted as follows:

```
exports.GetShort = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    const longURL = request.query.long;
    functions.logger.info("url is - ", longURL)
    SaveToDB(longURL)
    .then(() => {
        response.status(200).send('Saved to DB');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // See video series
        response.status(500).send(error);
    })
})


function SaveToDB(link) {
    functions.logger.info("here")
    return admin.firestore().collection("url").where("urlNames", "array_contains", link).get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        functions.logger.info("snap, ", querySnapshot)
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            functions.logger.info("things :  ", doc.id, " => ", doc.data())

            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            
            // => Here, depending on your real functional requirements, you may need to use Promise.all()
            
        });
        return null;
    }
    ).catch(function (error) {
        functions.logger.info("Error getting documents: ", error);
        // Throw an error
    });
}
```

Comment: The things you have said are right. 

However, the code you gave still does not work. It crashes down after printing "here". What I think is, it should have at-least printed "snap, ******" and then crash. 
Dont know why the code behaves weird.

Comment: Try to initialise the DB following the suggestions and the codes in this link here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#node.js_1

Comment: @Abhishek No error message? What happens if you remove the `where` clause (`return admin.firestore().collection("url").get().then(querySnapshot => {`)? Also, can you share the content of your `package.json` file (under the `functions` directory)

Comment: @Allennick Doing `const functions = require("firebase-functions"); const admin = require("firebase-admin"); admin.initializeApp();` in a Cloud Function shall be OK normally, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, Added contents of packages.json in the question. Also, removing where clause does not create any error and code runs properly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem. Sometimes silly things make most of the noise around.
Instead of "array-contains", I wrote "array_contains".

Comment: @Abhisek Glad that you found the problem! You may upvote my answer which, IMHO, helped you to debug your code (see my comments) and shared some key points about Cloud Functions life cycle.